# Meteor No longer Live-Reload when changing code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, livereload

For some unknown reason my meteor project is no longer refreshing itself whenever I change the code. I don't even know where to start debugging it, since looking at google didn't show any result either. here is my package and meteor version.

```
meteor-base@1.2.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.5       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.3.0                   # The database Meteor supports right now
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-js@2.2.0    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.9.0              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

kadira:flow-router      # FlowRouter is a very simple router for Meteor
less@2.7.11                    # Leaner CSS language
static-html
fourseven:scss@4.5.4
aldeed:collection2-core@2.0.0
aldeed:schema-deny
reywood:publish-composite
fortawesome:fontawesome
keepnox:perfect-scrollbar
accounts-password@1.5.0
matb33:collection-hooks
meteortoys:allthings
check
alanning:roles
ostrio:files
dynamic-import@0.2.0
aldeed:tabular
easy:search
thereactivestack:blazetoreact
harrison:papa-parse
session@1.1.7
planefy:paypal-ipn-listener
meteorhacks:picker
dburles:collection-helpers
meteorhacks:aggregate
email@1.2.3
twbs:bootstrap
tmeasday:publish-counts
deanius:promise
momentjs:moment
percolate:synced-cron
seba:minifiers-autoprefixer
infinitedg:gsap
okgrow:analytics
verron:autosize
nitrolabs:cdn
practicalmeteor:mocha
shell-server
fongandrew:login-as-user
```

**My Meteor** version is METEOR@1.6 and I am using react as my front end

Comment: Have you tried updating to Meteor @1.6.0.1 patch?

Comment: I had updated it just a few moment ago but it 's still not working

Comment: Is it happening on changing both client files and server files?

Comment: yes, in the terminal the client/server has successful restarted is logged is just the browser is not auto reload

Comment: I found the problem related to one of my component. but i have no idea why, it was a component with state and composer when i disable it but only sometime which is strange same code but sometime it work sometime it dont.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to componentDidUpdate calling async method which it is called more than once resulting error that prevent live reload to reload.